# My website isn't updating when I add files to it?

Tags: godaddy-api

when i added the files in GoDaddy filemanager.. my website didn't change the content. It shows a GoDaddy content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvr4.png)

how to clear this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your inspect this HTML page you will not see any trace of your work. Check your configuration, which page is launch while get your URL. How did you deploy your work?

Answer (score 0):

do you upload your published website to your host??
check if index.html or defualt.html or … is exist remove them and use your index website page

Comment: i put the index.html file only, but it's not working

Comment: if you don't have any file else and just index it should display your index page, If possible, upload a picture of the host files or a index file